# Is it possible to enter data into a Website via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am collecting Data via Google Forms, they go into a Google Spreadsheet.
Then I would Google Apps Script to enter the Data into a Webpage Formular.
Is this possible in anyway with Google Apps Script?

Update:
I would like to do Google Apps Script, go to a website( I don’t have control of the website, then get data from a google spread sheet and enter it into the fields then click on certain fields. I know I could to it via puppeteer. But I was thinking google Apps Script has something/sometype to interact with websites.

Comment: Is the webpage made from Google Apps Script? Also, kindly show us what have you tried so far and you may also check [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Answer (score 1):

Not in the way you're thinking. If the target website is not secure you can "fake" a form submission on it by making a POST requesting using `UrlFetchApp`. But this will most likely not work on most sites.

You can use `UrlFetchApp` to get the target website but GAS won't render it or let you interact with it like puppeteer will.